# AMDGPU driver vramlimit

Tags: gpu, limit, amd-graphics, shared-memory

I have a console installation of debian and i found that from the available 16GB of ram i can see only 14GB, this is because my APU (AMD) is reserving 2GB which is way too much for my needs. The bad news is that i don't have a setting in bios to change that.

I saw in AMDGPU driver documentation the params `vramlimit` and `vis_vramlimit` (cpu visible vram) so i have some question for anybody that have played with this options.

- Restricting the amount o vram from AMDGPU driver should free the ram for the system or just limit the amount used of what is reserved in bios? (this will be the worst case scenario, having reserved 2GB for video but not even use all of them if is needed).
- What is exactly doing `vis_vramlimit` as from the description i don't get it exactly what it means for the system.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem and my BIOS Setup dont allow to me change the ammount of shared Video RAM, but i found the documentation of these parameters. I need to check if that works.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/gpu/amdgpu.html

*UPDATE*
Using this for example `vis_vramlimit=1024 vramlimit=1024 gartsize=128 gttsize=512` the GPU use only that RAM, but the BIOS dont let the SO catch the free RAM, so, without BIOS support is in vane.